# Stage class not converting when using pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I am writing a play with `\documentclass{stage}`. When I use pandoc to convert it into docx, the "stage" part isn't converted. Is there any iption I have to enable in pandoc to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

No.‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎